# Android how to open pdf at specific page from code

Tags: android, acrobat

I have coded to open a pdf in Android, passing the file name via a uri and Acrobat reader displays the file succesfully.   I have found details of parameters that can open Acrobat reader from a command line and tell it which page to display but I dont know how I can implement this via the uri, please help if it can be done.